# Удалить элемент из ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Привет! Есть такая выборка:

```
2.2.3 :038 > i
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Issue id: 110253, tracker_id: 5, project_id:
18, subject: "Разработка заявки ", 
description: "Необходимо разработать ...", 
due_date: nil, category_id: nil, status_id: 2, assigned_to_id: 2529,
priority_id: 4, fixed_version_id: nil, author_id: 3016, lock_version: 49,
created_on: "2016-04-21 11:23:51", updated_on: "2016-08-09 07:14:35",
start_date: "2016-04-21", done_ratio: 0, estimated_hours: nil, parent_id:
nil, root_id: 110253, lft: 1, rgt: 2, is_private: false, closed_on: nil>, 
#<Issue id: 112486, tracker_id: 4, project_id: 18, subject: "и о...", description: "В необходимо:\r\n1) Пр...", due_date: nil, category_id: 
nil, status_id: 13, assigned_to_id: 2529, priority_id: 4, fixed_version_id: 
nil, author_id: 3016, lock_version: 18, created_on: "2016-05-23 07:07:38", 
updated_on: "2016-08-08 14:40:30", start_date: "2016-05-23", done_ratio: 0, 
estimated_hours: nil, parent_id: nil, root_id: 112486, lft: 1, rgt: 2, 
is_private: false, closed_on: nil>]>
```

Мне нужно из этой выборки убрать, допустим, элемент с ID 112486. Если сделать так: `i.delete(112486)` то элемент удалятся полностью из базы. Как удалить его именно из этой выборки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как один из возможных вариантов

```
i = i.reject{|x| x.id == 112486}
```